# SAP NetWeaver Process Integration (PI)

Tags: sap-pi

How to check if SAP PI is running?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://help.sap.com/nwpi, please do some research yourself, that information is readily available from SAP documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Simply go to SAP PI's web start page `http://<host>:<port>/rep`

From there you should be able to drill down into the main monitoring functions to see all information on both the ABAP and JAVA stacks and their health.